# ¿Acceder a otra clase por medio de hilos en Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, hilos

Hola tengo un proyecto en android studio el cual guarda la ubicación del usuario (longitud y latitud), para ello he creado una serie de métodos en una sola Activity, ahora lo que necesito es que cuando el usuario cambie de activity me siga guardando la ubicación, he creado un hilo en otra activity para llamar el metodo donde se guarda la ubicación en el otro Activity pero me muestra un error null.
Aqui dejo el código del hilo:

```html
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity implements TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener{
   
    Activity1 x;
    
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        x=new Activity1();
        time time=new time();
        ejecutar();
    }
    
    public void hilo(){
        Thread t=new Thread();
        try{
            Thread.sleep(600000);
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        t.start();
    }

    public void ejecutar(){
        x.GuardarUbicacion();//aqui manda el error
        time time=new time();
        time.execute();
    }

    public class time extends AsyncTask <Void, Integer,Boolean>{

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            hilo();
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Boolean aBoolean){
            ejecutar();
            Toast.makeText(Activity2.this, "La ubicacion se guarda cada 10min", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Error:
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Looper android.content.Context.getMainLooper()' on a null object reference

Comment: Cuando se trabaja con Threads no es posible llamar instancias externas en funciones async, yo te recomendaria que la creacion del Activity lo dejes dentro del ejecutar().

Espero te ayude esto.

Comment: @pachecoton gracias por responder entonces deberia crear todo los metodos de guardar ubicacion en cada activity?

Comment: No, mi estimado.
Deberias de crear una clase especialmente para el proceso de la ubicacion sin extencion activity, para que puedas llamarlo desde cualquier activity.

Comment: ohh ya entiendo, bueno lo voy a intentar, gracias

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que tienes que esperar por el hilo de Interfaz (UI) de la actividad principal (los metodos se deben sincronizar). Puedes modificar el metodo *GuardarUbicacion* de esta manera:

```
public void GuardarUbicacion(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
       // Tu codigo aqui
    }
});
```

Recuerda tambien utilizar el contexto correcto con "getContext()" en la actividad principal.